# Unable to install MySQL-python

Tags: django, mysql-python, setuptools

Okay I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04

Only to be faced by a lot of problems. I am a newbie at this so you might have to tell me in a little more detail or step-by-step

I had a django project that was working perfectly but now it gives me this error :

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

or in python :

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Anyways I thought there was some problem with my MySQL-python so I tried re-installing it.

```
sudo pip install mysql-python
```

gives :

```
Downloading/unpacking mysql-python
  Running setup.py egg_info for package mysql-python
    The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available,
    and can't be installed while this script is running. Please
    install a more recent version first, using
    'easy_install -U distribute'.

    (Currently using distribute 0.6.24dev-r0 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages))
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available,

and can't be installed while this script is running. Please

install a more recent version first, using

'easy_install -U distribute'.



(Currently using distribute 0.6.24dev-r0 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages))

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 2 in /tmp/pip-build/mysql-python
Storing complete log in /home/nabeel/.pip/pip.log
```

If I do :

```
sudo easy_install -U distribute
```

It gives this error :

```
Searching for distribute
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/distribute/
Reading http://packages.python.org/distribute
Best match: distribute 0.6.29
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.29.tar.gz#md5=1aad767bfca8bebaccafee25f85696cf
Processing distribute-0.6.29.tar.gz
Running distribute-0.6.29/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-K8ZuMX/distribute-0.6.29/egg-dist-tmp-Fj0gj_
Before install bootstrap.
Scanning installed packages
Setuptools installation detected at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Egg installation
Patching...
Renaming /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg.OLD.1350776909.4
Patching complete.
Relaunching...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/easy_install", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('distribute==0.6.8', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1708, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1696, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1712, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 236, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 471, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 501, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 680, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 957, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 946, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 29, in run_setup
    lambda: execfile(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 70, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 31, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 131, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-K8ZuMX/distribute-0.6.29/distribute_setup.py", line 368, in _before_install
  File "/tmp/easy_install-K8ZuMX/distribute-0.6.29/distribute_setup.py", line 441, in _fake_setuptools
  File "/tmp/easy_install-K8ZuMX/distribute-0.6.29/distribute_setup.py", line 450, in _relaunch
NameError: global name '_cmd1' is not defined
```

Again now I have gone to this link :
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.6c11
to download and install setuptools..
I have also installed the latest distribute 0.6.8 from here :
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/0.6.8

I have also tried uninstalling the previous versions and installing back but it doesn't seems to work.
I have got Python 2.7.3 installed

Could someone please explain to me what is going on... How I can install Mysqldb...

I have also ran these commands on shell :

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client python-mysqldb libmysqlclient-dev python-dev
```

But it didn't help ...

**UPDATE I JUST DID THIS AND GOT THIS ERROR :**

```
nabeel@nabeel-pc:~$ pip uninstall setuptools
Uninstalling distribute:
  /usr/bin/easy_install
  /usr/bin/easy_install-2.7
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.24dev_r0.egg-info
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy_install.pyc
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.pyc
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/site.pyc
  /usr/share/pyshared/easy_install.py
  /usr/share/pyshared/pkg_resources.py
  /usr/share/pyshared/site.py
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled distribute
nabeel@nabeel-pc:~$ sudo easy_install -U distribute
Searching for distribute
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/distribute/
Reading http://packages.python.org/distribute
Best match: distribute 0.6.29
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.29.tar.gz#md5=1aad767bfca8bebaccafee25f85696cf
Processing distribute-0.6.29.tar.gz
Running distribute-0.6.29/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-Xcer8d/distribute-0.6.29/egg-dist-tmp-K0E7gP
Before install bootstrap.
Scanning installed packages
Setuptools installation detected at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Egg installation
Already patched.
After install bootstrap.
Creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info
Creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools.pth
Removing distribute 0.6.8 from easy-install.pth file
Adding distribute 0.6.29 to easy-install.pth file
Installing easy_install script to /usr/local/bin
Installing easy_install-2.7 script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.29-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for distribute
Finished processing dependencies for distribute
nabeel@nabeel-pc:~$ sudo pip install mysql-python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

**UPDATE 2 :**
I have managed to install virtualenv
now in the environment I have also managed to install MySQLdb.
Here's theh error I get while running my server :

```
sudo python manage.py syncdb
```

I get this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


(myenv)nabeel@nabeel-pc:~/workspace/gteam/metrics$ python
    Python 2.7.3 (default, Oct  6 2012, 21:57:36) 
    [GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import MySQLdb
    >>> exit()
```

Comment: Can you have it installed in virtualenv? That's actually better but maybe you have some specific requirements.

Comment: @robert-smith I haven't tried virtualenv yet.. I have never used it so I am not sure.. If you want I can try that and then let you know the response

Comment: @RobertSmith I have added a new update on my question... Could you please read that

Comment: No problem, writing answer :-)

Answer (score 39):

Using virtualenv

First things first. Make sure you have Mysql, Setuptools and some essentials:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essential
```

Now install VirtualEnv:

```
sudo easy_install -U virtualenv
```

Create a Virtual Environment. As the [documentation](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#what-it-does) says: `virtualenv is a tool to create isolated Python environments.` This means that the chances of getting a conflict are really small. Here "myenv" is the name of a folder where you can access your environment, so create it where you want.

```
virtualenv --distribute myenv
```

Then go to "myenv" directory and run this to activate it:

```
source myenv/bin/activate
```

You need to install libmysqlclient-dev to get MySQL-python working:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Now you're ready to install MySQL-python:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

and everything should be working.

When you don't want to work in that environment anymore, write in the terminal:

```
deactivate
```

**UPDATE**:

Since this answer keeps getting upvotes, let me show you how to do the same using conda, which has become my favorite environment nowadays. First you have to install anaconda (I believe you can also install miniconda, which is a lighter version that includes conda and some packages.)  [Here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) you will find the installer for Linux, OS X and Windows. It is a big file but contains a lot of pre-compiled packages ready to be installed. Assuming you already have installed anaconda, you can simply run:

```
conda create -n mysql-env python
```

`mysql-env` is the name of the environment (you can call it whatever you want) and `python` is the default version of python to be installed (currently, 2.7.10). Alternatively, install other version of python with `conda create -n my-new-env python=3.4`.

Then you activate your environment:

```
source activate mysql-env
```

and finally install mysql-python:

`conda install MySQL-python`

(I think `conda install mysql-python` also works)

And that's all.

Comment: It worked perfectly. How can I make it to run in my original environment rather then the virtual one ?

Comment: Well, that's the whole point of using virtual environments. You don't want to run all that in your main environment because it can create conflicts as you know but if you really want to try to fix your main environment, try this to solve your last error: curl http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py | python. However, I recommend you to use virtualenv always. Another suggestion: Install newer versions of Ubuntu from a fresh install instead of upgrading. It will save you some troubles.

Comment: @RobertSmith... Well that's good. I have managed to install MySQLdb but nothing after that...
I have updated my question in the update 2 ... virtual environment is not able to run my project either

Comment: Did you install Django using your new environment: pip install Django ?

Comment: @RobertSmith.. At This point I am ready to install a fresh install.. Can you please guide me through as to how I can do that by removing the current and installing a fresh one.
btw Thanks for your time and answers :)

Comment: Yes Django is installed in the new environment

Comment: Well, if you really want to do a fresh install, download the version of Ubuntu that you want. Beware there is a recent update Ubuntu 12.10 but it's not as stable (yet) as 12.04. Anyway, first backup all your files, download the iso file they offer, burn it to a DVD and start your computer with your DVD. The installer will ask you whether you want a fresh install, upgrade and other options if you have partitions. After that, everything will be fine and this time, use virtualenv :-)

Comment: Thanks :)
I don't have a DVD right now... I would do it later..
I am done for today.. couldn't even run my past project the whole day .. :/
Anyways... Thanks for so much of your time and help. :)

Comment: No problem. Sorry it didn't work the way you wanted. You could try to debug your last issue, though. Of course, after taking a break.

Comment: By the way, I just tested Django in virtualenv and it worked flawlessly. I hope you won't have more problems after a fresh install. You can also start a new question with this particular issue, a bit harder though.

Answer (score 11):

`easy_install -U distribute` solved my problem

Comment: Yes it is actually what pip recommends you do as well, I also overlooked it at first.

Comment: Just make sure your correct environment is active if you're using `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 4):

In some Ubuntu installations, you'll also want to consider libmysqlclient-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

It also held me back.  The other responders probably already had it installed and didn't realize it was required.