# Installing MySQL-python with pip, get "failed with error code 1"

Tags: python, mysql, django, visual-studio-2010, command-prompt

I'm using Django 1.8 with Python 3.4 in a virtualenv on Windows Vista, and I'm trying to connect a MySQL database to my project. However I realized that I need to have MySQL-python installed to do that.

So I tried to install MySQL-python from command prompt with this pip command:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

And I got an error message saying:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).
```

I went to download Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 but it said I had a more recent version installed already (I think I installed Visual 2013 some time ago).

I don't understand why it wouldn't work with a more recent version of Visual C++, and I can't find any answers anywhere.

If someone could help me resolve this issue that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/12993845/3945375

Comment: @Gocht this is for Linux :/

Comment: I remember having this issue a lot on Windows.  WinPython comes with many useful tools pre-installed, including SQL connectors. http://winpython.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Or you can use wheel packages for windows from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient

Comment: @Dawid are the wheel packages better to use than the source code version?

Comment: @NotInternetExplorer wheel packages are binaries compiled for specific version of python: 2.7, 3.4, 32bit or 64bit (not windows platform as you can have 32bit python on 64bit windows XD) so they're easy to install, no compilation is needed. I think if there is a compiled version why not to use it, unless you need specific options enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to look at the [open issues on Github for this project](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/issues). In particular take a look at issue [98](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/issues/98):

> mysqlclient is the de-facto successor of MySQL-python.
>
> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient

It appears that `mysql-python` is no longer maintained and is a legacy version, as the [Github project page states](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1#mysqldb1).

Good luck.

Comment: thanks, I tried that but it still won't work. I'm not sure if I downloaded it properly. I downloaded the source code version (.tar) to my virtualenv, and unpacked it. Still get the same error.